# No se encuentran los elementos del DOM introducidos con JS mediante fetch

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch

Estoy agregando publicaciones al html desde un archivo.txt y cuando quiero recorrerlos no los encuentra.

```
const publicarArticulo = (title)=>{
    const div = document.createElement("DIV");
    const h6 = document.createElement("h6");
    
    div.classList.add("publication");
    h6.classList.add("info-publication");

    h6.textContent = title;

    div.appendChild(h6);

    return div;
}

const cargarPublicacion = async () =>{
    
    const request = await fetch("articles.txt");
    const content = await request.json();
    const arr = content.articles;
    const documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[contador] != undefined){
            const newPublicacion = publicarArticulo(arr[contador].image,arr[contador].title,arr[contador].price)
            documentFragment.appendChild(newPublicacion);
            contador++;
        }
    }
    container.appendChild(documentFragment);
}
cargarPublicacion();


const articles = document.querySelectorAll(".info-publication");
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  console.log(articles)
});
```

No aparece nada por consola. (Ni undeffined ni un error)
Tambien probe agregando los elementos en el propio html y asi si funciona el console.log y los muestra como un NodeList.
Utitlizando un setTimout si me funciona pero me va a generar problemas en un futuro.

Comment: Porque las funciones asíncronas devuelven una Promesa. Debes esperar a que la misma se resuelva para poder ver el resultado que esperas

Comment: utilize then y ya funciona excelente, muchas gracias